# put html in a custom javascript message box

Tags: javascript, html

How can I put HTML in custom JavaScript message box? I have an HTML file and I want to load its content (not its code) in a message box. In front of my `var` I can write HTML code and it works good, but I want to load HTML with a lot of code in a separate file. Here is my JS code:

```
var showreadylist = function(element) {
    var div = //any code that i could load my html here ! ;
    div.click(function(event) {
        $(".vote-notification").fadeOut("fast", function() { $(this).remove(); });
    });

    var where = where || 'parent';

    if (where == 'parent'){
        element.parent().append(div);
    }
    else {
        element.after(div);
    }

    div.fadeIn("fast");
};
```

Comment: As you're already using jQuery, use a modal dialog. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: There are no default javascript messagebox you can fill with html, but there are a lot of great dialog and notification frameworks out there that makes it easy for you. Alertify and Toastr springs to mind. Bootstrap also has some components to do that.

Comment: thanks for your replay , and your info !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are able to use your custom js box as mentioned in description,

I am just providing you option to get data from html via ajax and append to your target div.

I am not sure about click event handler, but you need to handle in this way, this is just example code provided by you.

Sample code is as below

```
var showreadylist = function(element) {
    var div = //any code that i could load my html here ! ;
    $.get("htmlfile", function(data){
     div = data;

    div.click(function(event) {
        $(".vote-notification").fadeOut("fast", function() { $(this).remove(); });
    });

    var where = where || 'parent';

    if (where == 'parent'){
        element.parent().append(div);
    }
    else {
        element.after(div);
    }

    div.fadeIn("fast");

    });
};
```

Comment: thanks for your replay +1... i want to load html only ! the face of message box is not important for me i want its info ! that came from my data base !

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use bootstrap modals

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Or JQuery Ui's dialog box

http://jqueryui.com/dialog